# Do you run demos in production or have a separate demo environment?

Tags: testing, saas, software-distribution, demo

It's a pretty common query that I find comes up in SaaS applications. Do you run demos in production or in a separate demo environment?

It's slightly different to testing in production, which again is a hotly debated and controversial topic, but it is similar in principle.

On one hand, it means you'll have a clean production environment, free of demo accounts, on the other hand, running demos in production means one less environment to maintain, and means that demos it's always up to date with production.

Like with most things, it seems to be a tradeoff, with no obvious answer, it depends.

So, I'm asking this question as a way to get feedback, what do you do? What have you tried? What works for you, what doesn't? Do you have any examples of when either approach has worked for you, and when it has not?